# How to keep keyboard open on TextField even after AnimatedSwitcher switch?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am use AnimatedSwitcher for switch between 2 widget:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  child:
  toggle
      ? TextField()
      : otherWidget(),
```

Problem is when AnimatedSwitcher switch away from Textfield it dismiss keyboard even if user have already click on it and open keyboard.

How to keep keyboard open even if widget is switch?

Answer (score 0):

Same Here I was also trying to implement this in my app with form but the keyboard is getting closed as soon as user pressed textfield.

When I removed the key parameter for each child of AnimatedSwitcher widget then everything is working as expected.

Here is the code

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      child: showFirstContainer
          ? Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.amber,
            )
          : Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
    ),
```